# How can I access a method in a controller that is defined in a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm pretty new to rails, and the project I'm working on requires me to access an existing method. However, it's written in a model, and I'm not sure how I can get it to run in the controller my API needs to hit

I've tried routing to the method in the model, but learned I can't do that. From what I've gathered, this is sort of the way it will work, right?

**model.rb**

```
def method_i_need
 //code
end
```

**controller.rb**

```
def method_to_call_other_method
 //code
end
```

Comment: Get an instance of that model (one way or another) and call that method on it.

Comment: You can just change it to a class method, e.g. `def self.method_i_need` and then call it with `Model.method_i_need`

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of stealing @sergio's points...

If your method is defined inside Model.rb, then both the following will work in your controller:

```
def method_to_call_other_method
 Model.first.method_i_need
end


def method_to_call_other_method
 Model.find(params[:id]).method_i_need
end
```

As the commentor said, you just need an instance of your model (Model.first or Model.find(params[:id])) and to then call the method you defined in your model, on the instance of the model. And the params[:id] is obviously dependent on what params you're getting through.

Comment: Or even `Model.new.method_i_need`. Works with an empty database and no params :)

Answer (score 1):

Any instance of a class will have the public instance methods available to be called on the instance object. It's very common to instantiate model class instances within a controller action.
Here's an example elaborating on previous answer and comments how you can do this in Rails.

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  def say_hello 
    language == 'DE' ? 'Guten Tag' : 'Hello'
  end
end

class PersonsController < ApplicationController
  def random_person 
    @random_person = Person.find(Person.pluck(:id).sample)  
    # you can now call @random_person.say_hello
  end

  def person_greetings
    # this examples assumes we only have 2 languages, EN and DE
    languages = Person.pluck(:language).uniq.sort
    @greetings = languages.each_with_object({}) do |language, hash|
      hash[language] = Person.new(language: language).say_hello 
    end 
  end
end  

# @greetings should return the following hash
=> {
    "DE" => "Guten Tag",
    "EN" => "Hello"
}
```

Likewise, class methods can also be called directly when needed inside a controller action method for example in model you may have a class method defined like this inside the Person model.

```
def self.languages
  pluck(:language).uniq.sort
end
```

This method can be called from any controller or other classes where appropriate for example:

```
def languages
  @people_count = Person.count # active record method to get number of people in database
  @languages = Person.languages
end
```

Where you might use this inside of a controller action's view

```
<div> 
  There are <%= @people_count %> total people in the system.
  Of them, <%= @languages.count %> languages are spoken.
  Those include the following:
  <ol>
    <% @languages.each do |language| %>
      <li><%= language %></li>
  </ol>
</div>
```